# jquery to change css for next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a page called android.html with a button with an id of "detect". When you click the button, a script checks to see what OS version you have on your android device by the us header. How would I change the script to apply a style if it is version 3.0 or higher and another style if it is version 2.9 and lower. Here is the hard part...I dont want to apply the css style to the android.html page, but to the playlist.html page that you will redirected to on the click of the button.

html

```
<div id="detect">button</div>
```

js

```
$('#detect').click(function() {
if (/Android (\d+(?:\.\d+)+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ 
 var version=new Number(RegExp.$1) 
 if (version>=3)
  //redirect to playlist.html using style1.css
 }
else
 //redirect to playlist.html using style2.css
});
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to just do that check in document.ready on the playlist page and load the appropriate stylesheet at that point as opposed to having two separate redirects?

Comment: Agreed. You should really to that check in the playlist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either append a query-string key/value pair to the redirect that lets the next page know which style-sheet to load, or just check the user-agent string when the next page loads.

```
$('#detect').click(function() {
    if (/Android (\d+(?:\.\d+)+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ 
        var version=new Number(RegExp.$1) 
        if (version>=3)
            window.location = 'playlist.html?style=1';
        } else {
            window.location = 'playlist.html?style=2';
        }
    }
});
```

Then on the `playlist.html` page:

```
if (window.locaion.search.indexOf('style=1') > -1) {
    $.getScript('style1.css');
} else if (window.locaion.search.indexOf('style=2') > -1) {
    $.getScript('style2.css');
}
```

This `if/then` check is pretty simple. A better way to do it would be to get the query-string parameters in an array, check for the `style` key, then load the corresponding value.

Comment: @Blainer I just updated my answer with how to check the `window.location.search` property for a value. If you are using a server-side scripting language like PHP, I recommend doing this check server-side rather than client-side.

Comment: for some reason when i click the button its not even redirecting me to the playlist.html at all.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to that html page with a query string, i.e playlist.html?css=v1 or v2, then check for that GET param in the next page and include the appropriate css file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to pass a query string variable to the redirect specifying the "anversion", and check that variable and insert the .css file based on the value on the second page.